# Google Maps API: colouring locations

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Apologies if this is dead simple..

I can see that it's possible to draw on an area using overlays, but is it possible to just draw(colour) a location (a pair of longitude and latitude coordinates)?

I need to colour a map by specifying a colour for every location I have available in my database.

I'm also a bit concerned about the speed.

Any ideas/advice welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lat/lon pair represents a point, and a point has zero size. You cannot color something that has no size, therefore you need to represent those points with something bigger than a point, like a marker or a polygon, both of which are overlays.

Comment: I was afraid of an answer like that but was hoping that a pair of coordinates is more like a pixel in an image - it's a point but has a size and you can set its colour.

Anyway I'll just make little squares :)

Comment: lat/lon can be converted to a pixel. A pixel is like a "little square", (bigger than a point with no size), and how much "lat height" and "lon width" the pixel represents depends on the zoom level of the map and on the latitude.

Comment: indeed, you would need to use Polygons, to add "surface area" or use a map marker thats colored differently for each location.. You could use php to generate a different marker color randomly for each location point.